# Python (reverse a string)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello everyone im trying to reverse a string in python but i cant get it to work. I tried using reversed but it didnt work. I found the replacment for it but it i cant get it to work properly. Explenanation and help would be appriciated.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb3Du.png)

```
word="cba"
word[::1]
print (word)
```

Comment: `word[::1]` That doesn't do anything, you're not assigning it to anything.

Comment: try `print(word[::1])` to check the final result

Comment: don't you mean `print(word[::-1])`

Comment: @ρss works just forgot the - before 1

Comment: @AChampion you spotted my typo. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not `word[::1]`, but `word[::-1]`: it's a [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings) with step -1. But I can't understand your problems with [reversed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) - it's even more simple: `reversed(word)`.

Comment: `reversed` returns a generator so you would need `''.join(reversed(word))` to get the same result as `word[::-1]`

Comment: Just changing the 1 to -1 in the OP's code [won't change what gets printed](http://ideone.com/twE7dc).